# variable lat and long are not set to global variable they does not contain value assign in function It always give me undefined whenever i check them

Tags: javascript

i have to use lat and long in loc() method and injecting loc() in component It always give me undefined whenever i check them, i'm new to  js so answer accordingly ..:-)

@Injectable()

export class WheatherService {
    private req: any;

constructor(private http: Http) { }

loc() {

return this.http.get('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + 
lat + '&lon=' + long + '&APPID=d9c05681b9c98fd7185573a204400f74&units=metric').map(response => response.json());

}

var lat;

var long

function onSuccess(position) {

```
lat = position.coords.latitude;

long = position.coords.longitude;
```

}

if (navigator.geolocation) {

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess);

console.log(lat, long);
```

}

}

Answer (score 0):

Place console after function call (or)  use promise to solve this issue.

if (navigator.geolocation) {

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess);
console.log(lat, long);

}

using Promise:

```
var pro=new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
var lat;

var long;

function onSuccess(position) {

   lat = position.coords.latitude;

   long = position.coords.longitude;
   resolve({lat:lat,long:long})
 }

 if (navigator.geolocation) {

   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess);

 }
});

pro.then((data)=>{
  console.log(data.lat,data.long);
})
```

Note: Navigation API sometimes depends on browser support or protocol(https),Please check whether your app has location access.

Comment: hi , it is not working , i have to use value of lat, long in code written before this function

Comment: hi chandra, i have to use these variable in the code written above this code so can please suggest me something so that  these variable can hold the value

Comment: Sandeep its not possible to get lat,long values before calling geolocation API.

Comment: please check this code problem is i have to use the value of lat & long in loc()...... loc() {
        return this.http.get('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + long +
            '&APPID=d9c05681b9c98fd7185573a204400f74&units=metric').map(response => response.json());
    }

 var lat; 
var long; 
function onSuccess(position) {
lat = position.coords.latitude; 
long = position.coords.longitude; 
} 
if (navigator.geolocation) { 
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess);
   }

Comment: console after function call does not seems to work it still giving undefined

Comment: sandeep invoke loc() function inside onSuccess function

Comment: this is under my service class and i'm injecting loc() in another component. i'm new to js please help me if you can.

Comment: hi chandra, plz take look into it amd help me to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

First, you call `console.log` *before* you call `onSuccess`.  We can move `console.log` to after the call to `onSuccess`:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess);
}
console.log(lat, long);
```

You *define* the function `onSuccess` before the logging, but you don't *call* it until after the logging. `console.log` only occurs once.

However the logging still won't work as expected. This is because of JavaScript's [concurrency model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop). JavaScript functions run to completion, before processing asynchronous events. That is to say the code will run in this order:

```
1. if (navigator.geolocation) {
2.   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
4.     onSuccess
     )
   }
3. console.log(lat, long);
```

Since `onSuccess` doesn't run until *after* this block of code completes, `lat` and `long` are not set until after the asynchronous `getCurrentPosition` finishes getting the current position.

You can move the `console.log` into `onSuccess` to check.

Anything that depends on `lat` and `long` will really have to depend on `onSuccess`. You can't really use `lat` and `long` as global variables.

Comment: your solution is giving me undefined when i console.log(lat, long) i.e line 3

Comment: please check this code problem is i have to use the value of lat & long in loc()...... loc() { return this.http.get('api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat='; + lat + '&lon=' + long + '&APPID=d9c05681b9c98fd7185573a204400f74&units=metric').map(response => response.json()); } var lat; var long; function onSuccess(position) { lat = position.coords.latitude; long = position.coords.longitude; } if (navigator.geolocation) { navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess); }